# Lowering the height of a superscript?

Tags: superscripts

If I write `$\hat{\bar{M}}^{a}$` by using the code

```
\hat{\bar{M}}^{a}
```

then I find that the superscript `a` is too high up. I would like for that `a` to be at the same height as `M` (but including the bar and hat accents on top).

How does one do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
$\hat{\bar{M}}{}^{a}$ $\hat{\bar{M}}^{a}$
\end{document}
```

See, if use of `\widehat` instead of `\hat` gives more appealing result.

Answer (score 14):

If you load the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package, `\hat{\bar{M}}^{a}` will not only give you the desired, i.e., smaller height offset for the exponent term *automatically*, it'll also stack the "hat" and "bar" accent symbols in a much more pleasing way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\hat{\bar{M}}^{a}$
\end{document}
```