# How to lower the superscript in a math mode manually

Tags: amsmath, superscripts

I am using `amsmath` package, and I would like to print `$\dot{\overline{P}}^{A}$` such that the letter `A` was at the same height as in `$\overline{P}^{A}$`.

The order of upper symbols matters (`\dot` must be over `\overline`). Moving `A` inside `\dot{}` is also impossible since the dot moves horribly to the right. **So how can the superscript be lowered down manually?** Similar problem was asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574666/lowering-the-height-of-a-superscript), however, the solution doesn't work for me.

[image: symbol A at different heights]

Comment: Here is another possibility: [Lowering the height of a superscript?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/574666]

Comment: what does not work mean? they should work you haven't provided a test document but I would have suggested `\dot{\overline{P}}{}^{A}` which is one of the answers that you link to.

Comment: You always need to include a compilable MWE for others to test. The code that produces your picture will do nicely.

Comment: @David Carlisle, this works well. And you're right, this was in the answer, but I missed the empty `{}` hint in the code. With `amsmath` included I got other results than presented in the answer, and this must have confused me. Silly, I know :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Capture the height of `\overline{P}` via `{\vphantom{\overline{P}}}` and use that to add a superscript:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\dot{\overline{P}}^A$
$\overline{P}^A$
$\dot{\overline{P}}{\vphantom{\overline{P}}}^A$

\end{document}
```

The above solution uses content from [\vphantom and superscripts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165499/5764) - specifically, `{<vphantom>}^{<exp>}`.

Comment: Neat! Works like a charm :) Thank you.

Comment: Very nice solution. Good to know.

Comment: Or use `\vphantom` then no need to measure, `\dot{\overline{P}}\vphantom{\overline{P}}^A`

Comment: @daleif: This doesn't work as expected, since the height of the exponent is much lower.

Comment: @Werner that sounds odd, it should give exactly the same size as your settoheight

Comment: @daleif: My thoughts exactly. Try it. [Code](https://pastebin.com/raw/kWkXtz3N), [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JJdj.png).

Comment: @Werner I asked chat, try `{\vphantom{...}}`

Comment: Here is an explantion: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399245/3929

Comment: @daleif: Awesome!