# Lower the superscript of a hat variable

Tags: spacing, amsmath, superscripts

I have an inline math expression involving a superscript and a hat:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^{(k+1)}=\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^{(k)}+(\hat{F}^{(k)})^{-1} \hat{\mathbf{S}}_{\boldsymbol{\beta}}(\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}^{(k)}, \hat{\boldsymbol{\alpha}})$,
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

It looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the superscripts are pushing up the preceding line, which is not a behaviour I want. I would prefer the superscript was simply lowered to account for this. However, even though I have loaded `amsmath`, I'm not getting the behaviour described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/574680/169711.

How can I lower the superscripts in this situation?

Comment: Try `\bm` (with `bm` package) instead of `\boldsymbol`.

Comment: Oh huh, that actually does fix it. I had no idea the `\boldsymbol` was the problem.

Comment: Oh, but `\bm` doesn't work with `unicode-math`.

Comment: You can use `\symbf` with `unicode-math`.

Comment: Perfect, `\symbf` does the right thing!